# Magento - Backend only shows empty screen, how to show error instead?

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml

I am developing a extension, following the instructions of a magento developer book.

I get a blank screen after adding the file `adminhtml.xml` to the `etc` folder of my module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <branches translate="title" module="branches">
            <title>Branches</title>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
        </branches>
        <children>
            <list translate="title" module="branches">
                <title>List</title>
                <action>branches/adminhtml_branches</action>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            </list>
        </children>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <branches>
                        <title>Branches</title>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                    </branches>
                    <children>
                        <list translate="title">
                            <title>List</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </list>
                    </children>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

[image]

They even mentioned in the book that an error will appear at this point, but my question is, why is there no error but just a blank screen? How can I tell magento to show me the error instead?

---

I already activated developer mode, by adding this code to my `index.php`:

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    include 'app/code/local/Debug/ChromePhp.php';
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
}
```

But it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Use the following code in your `index.php` file

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

Just paste it at the top. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276042/4684797).

**Warning!**

Only use this in developement servers, don't use it on your production site, it might reveal security vulnerabilities to hackers.

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting with php configuration or from index.php , also your errors might be visible on page source (view source) or in server php error logs

Comment: Does not work, I activated developer mode but it does still show an empty gray screen. See my updated question.